# Are there platforms that do not support uint64_t?

Tags: multiplication, implementation, uint64, uint32

I am working on a project that relies on the standard C datatype `uint64_t` to multiply 32 bit integers. But I am concerned about portability issues, as I am already re-implementing many parts of my source code in `C` due to portability reasons. I realize that it is difficult to provide an exhaustive list, but due to lack of hardware resources, available to me, I know the specs of my systems (PC (Windows, x86) / Android phones based on ARM etc. ) only. My target project, needs to run on a wide variety of platforms like Arduino,  embedded systems etc. And I was wondering whether I should replace, `uint64_t` with an alternative like two `uint32_t`variables, to store the high and low bits of my 64 bit number...

Sorry, for this direct question. But I intend to strike up a detailed discussion of implementing my multiplication faster and in constant time.

Thankyou very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To deal with some 32 bit systems, that approach can make sense.